# How long does a bottled beer last

Tags: bottling, aging

I am making a trappist style beer and about ready to bottle it. I am looking to age part of the bottles and was wondering how long bottled homebrew stays good for?

Comment: This is hugely dependent on the kind of beer you're brewing and what you mean by 'last' - trappist ales generally age well as long as your sanitation and bottling procedures are to a high-standard

Comment: I am a meticulous sanitizer. Just a question though. I have always filled my buckets/carboys with 5 gallons of star sans solution to sanitize it, and since I don't have the space I would dump the solution afterwards. This is wasteful and costly, so due to a response from another question I posted here, I was planning of mixing 1 gallon of solution and thoroughly shaking it in the bottling bucket to sanitize it. Is it a bad idea to try this sanitation method on bottles I plan to age for a good while (like a year)?

Comment: Please post that as a separate question.